# Вставка обектов в БД, Hibernate

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, hql

MySQL.
Есть такая таблица, со связями многие к одному.
[image]
Каждая колонка связана с соответствующей таблицей, в которой два поля: ID и текст. 
В проекте для каждой таблицы создал класс c анатациями.
Вот класс главной таблицы

```
@Entity
@Table(name ="main")
public class Schedule {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "ID")
    private int id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "Date_of_schedule_ID")
    private DateOfSchedule dateOfSchedule;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "Group_of_student_ID")
    private GroupOfStudent groupOfStudent;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "Time_of_lesson_ID")
    private TimeOfLesson timeOfLesson;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "Study_ID")
    private Study study;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "Professor_ID")
    private Professor professor;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "Type_ID")
    private Type type;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    @JoinColumn(name = "Classroom_ID")
    private Classroom classroom;
```

С загрузкой из БД через Hibernate объекта Scgedule из этой таблицы все отлично. Данные из замапленных таблиц загружаются и я получаю заполненный объект Schedule.

А вот с загрузкой в БД проблемы,когда пытаюсь загрузить так

```
session.save(Schedule);
```

Возможно ли вообще чтобы при загрузке обекта Schedule в базу, связанные  таблицы заполнялись данными из полей объекта Schedule, а главная таблица заполнялась айдишниками?

Comment: "А вот с загрузкой в БД проблемы", какая конкретно проблема?

Comment: Поля связанных с главной таблиц должны быть уникальными,а при вставке они естественно повторяются.Вылетает exception. Можно создать кеш и фильтровать через него, но это на крайний случай.

Comment: @Виктор `ConstraintViolationException: could not execute statement. ERROR: Duplicate entry`